# Makefile rule matching

Tags: makefile

In my gnu-make-3.81 Makefile, I wish to generate .o files from .s files if there is no .c source files. So I defined the following rules which I have simplified:

```
all::$(OBJS)

%.s: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -S $<

%.o: %.s
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

With gnu-make-3.81, when there is no .c source files, it will generate .o files using the second rule. But with gnu-make-3.82, there is a error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `xxx.c', needed by `xxx.s'.  Stop.
```

How can I make it work like gnu-make-3.81 ?

Comment: In 3.81, make chooses the first pattern rule that matches, whereas in 3.82, it chooses the first pattern rule with the shortest stem which matches.   This makes me think you oversimplified your example, and that you have multiple pattern rules to generate your .s files.  In your 3.81 invocation, how did your xxx.s get generated?

Comment: I have disabled implicit rules by set .SUFFIXES: empty. I use the same makefile in both 3.81 and 3.82. I suppose to generated .o files if there were only .s files supplied. If I delete the first rule, it works. If there were .s files in the dir, why make try the first rule and try to find the  c source file? @HardcoreHenry